# How calculate Diff in python

Tags: python, string, diff

I have two strings: *stringA* and *stringB*.

I want to calculate difference between *stringA* and *stringB* such that it only contains the difference between both. If I apply the difference on *stringA*, I should be able to get *stringB*.

In python there is `difflib`, but it does not computer diff as above it almost saves the content of both strings.

Example:

```
stringA = "apple\nball\n"
stringB = "apple\ncat\n"
```

Now difference should look like `-2,+2cat\n`, its just an example but I want difference to be minimum information.

Now if I apply the above difference to *stringA* I should get *stringB*.

Comment: It is not clear to me what you mean by "minimum information". If you don't want the context, use `difflib.unified_diff(..., n=0)`, otherwise please spend a few words explaining why this does not do what you want.

Comment: Hi Thanks for the reply, following is my goal: I get an object A and send it to Alice, then I receive an object A' [almost A but few lines changed]. Now Instead of send the A' again I want to send the difference only so that Alice can apply this difference on A and get A'. 
When I tried to calculate the diff using difflib it appeared it was saving the common lines and differences as well. But I just want to send the difference to save the bandwidth. I hope it will help.

Comment: Doesn't `unified_diff` with `n=0` (and maybe with gzip compression) help?

Comment: Hi it seems to be working Thanks :D, can you please guide how I can recover the string now. 
`var = unified_diff(s1, s2, n=0)`
now if I apply var on s1 how I can get s2?

Comment: @AndreaCorbellini Thanks can you please help with the above comment I think that will solve my problem completely.

Comment: Thanks a lot everyone. Here is an other alternate approach: [http://code.google.com/p/google-diff-match-patch/wiki/API]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you do not want the context, just suppress it with by passing `n=0` to [`difflib.unified_diff()`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff):

```
>>> import difflib
>>> a = ['line 1\n', 'line 2\n', 'line 3']
>>> b = ['line 1\n', 'line 5\n', 'line 3']
>>> delta = list(difflib.unified_diff(a, b, n=0))
>>> delta
['--- \n', '+++ \n', '@@ -2 +2 @@\n', '-line 2\n', '+line 5\n']
```

You may further reduce the output size by compressing it using [`gzip`](https://docs.python.org/dev/library/zlib.html) or other algorithms.

Unfortunately, Python does not offer a way to restore unified diffs. You may write your own code (it's not that difficult) or use one of the existing libraries from the web (an example is [python-patch](https://github.com/techtonik/python-patch)).

You can also use the [`patch(1)`](http://linux.die.net/man/1/patch) tool available on most Unix systems.

Comment: Is there any example how to use python-patch, I am sorry I am new to programming.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [difflib](http://docs.python.org/library/difflib.html) library to do it. Look at `unified_diff` function.

Comment: This shouldn't be an answer as it is, especially since the OP mentioned `difflib` as not doing this. If `difflib` _can_ do this, you should explain how.

Comment: Hi hspandher thanks for the reply, as I mentioned difflib almost stores the the both strings the difference as well as common lines, I want to save only difference such that I should be able to recover the newstring if I apply the difference on old one.

Comment: How would you use `difflib.unified_diff` for this? Can you show an example? Just mentioning a function should be done in the comments to the question :).

Answer (score 0):

Use [difflib.unified_diff](https://docs.python.org/2/library/difflib.html#difflib.unified_diff) from the standard library.

```
>>> s1 = ['bacon\n', 'eggs\n', 'ham\n', 'guido\n']
>>> s2 = ['python\n', 'eggy\n', 'hamster\n', 'guido\n']
>>> for line in unified_diff(s1, s2, fromfile='before.py', tofile='after.py'):
...     sys.stdout.write(line)   
--- before.py
+++ after.py
@@ -1,4 +1,4 @@
-bacon
-eggs
-ham
+python
+eggy
+hamster
guido
```

Comment: How would you use `difflib.unified_diff` for this? Can you show an example? Just mentioning a function should be done in the comments to the question :).

Comment: but it also seems to be storing the the last line which is in common. plus how can I recover s1 give the the output of unified_diff.

Comment: Hi am using unified_diff as `var = unified_diff(s1, s2, n=0)`, can you please guide me how I can recover s2 by applying var on s1 somehow?